# Can I cancel SMS sending on iPhone while it is still in progress?

Tags: iphone, sms

Is it possible on iPhone to stop sending SMS while it is still in progress?

E.g. Accidentally pressed send. Or spotted a typo just after pressing send.

Comment: Not a proper response, but depending on actual mobile cell reception, if you are lucky and fast enough you may be able to turn on airplane mode or reboot your iPhone before it ends sending the SMS.

Comment: But if we could, there wouldn't sites like DamnYouAutocorrect ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a done deal when the Send button is hit, and there is no native way to cancel it, or delay the sending, so the user could have the opportunity to cancel.

If after pressing send you swipe upwards from the bottom of the screen and hit the flight mode button (top left) then the message will not be able to send. You need to be reasonably quick, but if you practice it a few times it does become easier, and works every time.

Comment: But if you can stop it with the flight mode. Then later on when you switch back to normal, it will continue sending it, right?!?

Comment: @Kate, I have not tested it, but you could probably delete the message while airplane mode is on.

Comment: Nope. In airplane mode you can't delete it either :/ My phone has been stuck two days on "sending" my location and the map is still searching my current location :S

Answer (score 0):

One way, but this only works in low signal areas (one or two bars at most) is I hold my hand tight around the lower half of my iPhone 3GS in attempt to cover the antenna and thus cause the phone to loose cell reception before it can finish sending the text.

Answer (score 0):

The only way WITHOUT jaiilbreak is to be speedy and enable airplane mode in control center, or reboot by holding power+home.  With jailbreak, you can set sending delays and many more things.

Answer (score 0):

If the message itself is sending slowly you can go to the top block the contact and/or go to settings turn off iMessage and turn on flight mode then power down. The only way you will know it worked is if when you power back up the green message icon displays a red exclamation mark on it and reads "message send failure".